# Node.js on macbook with m1 chip. 'npm run dev' presenting with error

Tags: php, node.js, npm, apple-m1, nvm

I finally managed to get node and npm versions showing after installing node and npm.

```
npm install
```

managed to work after it kept failing. I ran

```
npm init
```

and continuously hit enter then it worked after. Now whenever I run

```
npm run dev
```

i am presented with the following error;

```
    adnansaid@pc-200-38 smartMeals % npm run dev                   

> dev
> npm run development


> development
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

[webpack-cli] Error: [BABEL]: Cannot find module '@babel/helper-plugin-utils'
Require stack:
- /Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import/lib/index.js
- /Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/available-plugins.js
- /Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/filter-items.js
- /Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js
- /Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/module-types.js
- /Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/configuration.js
- /Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
- /Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/FileCollection.js
- /Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/tasks/Task.js
- /Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/tasks/ConcatenateFilesTask.js
- /Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Combine.js
- /Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentRegistrar.js
- /Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Mix.js
- /Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
- /Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js
- /Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js
- /Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
- /Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js (While processing: /Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import/lib/index.js:8:26)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import/lib/index.js',
    '/Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/available-plugins.js',
    '/Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/filter-items.js',
    '/Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js',
    '/Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/module-types.js',
    '/Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/configuration.js',
    '/Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js',
    '/Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js',
    '/Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/FileCollection.js',
    '/Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/tasks/Task.js',
    '/Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/tasks/ConcatenateFilesTask.js',
    '/Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/Combine.js',
    '/Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/components/ComponentRegistrar.js',
    '/Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Mix.js',
    '/Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js',
    '/Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js',
    '/Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js',
    '/Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js',
    '/Users/adnansaid/Desktop/MindSpace/smartMeals/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js'
  ]
}
```

What can I do to fix this, as i want to be able to begin working. When working on the older macbooks installing node.js was the easiest thing to do now it seems to be the most difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Install this npm package then try to run it

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

Comment: Same error... Not sure what is going on